# Explanation for SCP protocol implementation in JSch library

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, scp, jsch

I am contemplating over an example of JSch library usage which can be found here:
http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ScpFrom.java.html

I cannot understand several code patterns from this example. Here they are:

1. Is there any reasons to prefer SCP over SFTP, which can be ran using the same library?
2. Why we run `scp -f <remote file>` on remote host instead of running simply `scp source_file_path destination_file_path`? Why execution on remote host is better?
3. In the beginning of the transfer there is a line

   ```
   while(true){
   int c=checkAck(in);
   if(c!='C'){
       break;
   }
   ...
   ```

   what is the meaning of this magical `C` letter? Why `C`?
4. Why to send this signal all the time?

   ```
   // send '\0'
   buf[0]=0; out.write(buf, 0, 1); out.flush();
   ```
5. how this can read filesize?

   ```
   long filesize=0L;
   while(true){
       if(in.read(buf, 0, 1)<0){
           // error
           break; 
       }
       if(buf[0]==' ')break;
       filesize=filesize*10L+(long)(buf[0]-'0'); //What is this??
   }
   ```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> 1. Is there any reasons to prefer SCP over SFTP, which can be ran using the same library?

No, the SCP protocol is obsolete. You should always use SFTP nowadays.

*Though trivial implementations of the SFTP protocol tend to have slower transfers than SCP (it's not easy to implement the SFTP transfer efficiently due to its packet nature).*

> 2. Why we run `scp -f <remote file>` on remote host instead of running simply `scp source_file_path destination_file_path`? Why execution on remote host is better?

It's how SCP protocol works. The OpenSSH `scp` binary works both as a server and a client. So when you run `scp` locally, it connects over SSH and runs `scp` on the server. Then the two instances communicate with each other. The JSch replaces the local instance of the `scp`. But it still needs the remote instance to complete the transfer.

If you were running `scp` locally, you would have to have OpenSSH installed on the machine. What is maybe common on Unix, but definitely not on Windows. Also there's no easy/standardized way to capture results from the `scp` program, to translate them to JSch Java interface. It's the same reason why JSch (or any other SFTP library) implements SFTP protocol on its own, instead of using `sftp` program.

> 3. what is the meaning of this magical C letter? Why C?

Every command of the SCP protocol is identified by a single character. The `C` stands for "file transfer", `D` stands for "directory transfer", `T` before file transfer indicates modification time of the next transferred file, etc. I do not know why it's `C` and not for example `F`.

> 4. Why to send this signal all the time?

The NULL (`\0`) character command is confirmation/response to the other site that the received command was completed.

> 5. how this can read filesize?

The `C` command has syntax (it's a human-readable string):

```
C permissions size filename
```

For example:

```
C 0644 153634 index.php
```

The loop in the code translates the string `"153634"` to a number 153634. It looks like a bit too complicated implementation, but it works.

---

See also [How is SCP (secure copy protocol) file transfer working?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37558853/850848)

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/134901/whats-the-difference-between-scp-and-sftp