# How is SCP (secure copy protocol) file transfer working?

Tags: networking, sftp, file-transfer, scp

Please, tell me how does the SCP work.

Can anybody explain(or show) SCP file transfer to me (something looks like picture, flow or reference).
What were the differences between SCP and SFTP file transfer?

Thanks in advance, and sorry about my language.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The SCP client connects to the SSH server and executes `scp` command there. In most cases, the remote `scp` would be the OpenSSH `scp` command. That means, if you use the OpenSSH `scp` command as a client, the local `scp` (as a client) actually talks to the same program on the server. The remote `scp` is executed with undocumented `-t` (to) or `-f` (from) flags. This way, the `scp` program recognizes that it serves as a server.

Once the remote `scp` is running, it talks with the local SCP client (the `scp` or another implementation) using a simple protocol.

An SCP command is one-letter followed by some arguments and new-line.

An SCP response is one byte, with `0x00` = ok, `0x01` = error, `0x02` = fatal error (though the OpenSSH `scp` actually never responds with `0x02`). The error code is followed by an error message (terminated with a new-line).

It's always the source side that feeds the commands. The target side consumes them. I.e. when downloading, the server feeds the commands and the client consumes them. When uploading, the client feeds the commands and the server consumes them.

Commands are:

- `E` – exit
- `T` – sets timestamps for the upcoming file
- `C` – file transfer
- `D` – directory

---

See also [Explanation for SCP protocol implementation in JSch library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26220381/850848).

Comment: OK. thank a lot to you guy about SCP.