# How to transfer folder using scp using pem file.My Program showing no error but showing nothing(my files) on server

Tags: java, jsch

I am trying to transfer my folder using scp using a pem file

My whole program is executing fine but files in not showing on server.
Anyone can tell me where I am doing mistake

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;


public class jschclass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        String SFTPHOST = "xx.xxx.xx.xxx";
        int SFTPPORT = 22;
        String SFTPUSER = "myusername";
   //     String SFTPPASS = "password";
        String SFTPWORKINGDIR = "/var/www/html/projects/demoo_reports/";

        String Pemfilepath=System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.separator+"src"+File.separator+"lib"+File.separator+"airtel.pem";
        String targetFolder = System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.separator+"test-output";
    //String Pemfilepath="./src/lib/airtel.pem";

    //String targetFolder = "./test-output";
    File folder = new File("./test-output");

    System.out.println("folder=" + folder);
    if (folder.listFiles() != null) {
        List<File> listOfFiles = Arrays.asList(folder.listFiles());
        for (File file : listOfFiles) {
          //  System.out.println("File name: " + file.getName());
         //   System.out.println("Full path: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println("Target path: " + targetFolder + file.getName());
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    /////////////////////
    final JSch jsch = new JSch();
    try {
        jsch.addIdentity(Pemfilepath);
        System.out.println("identity added ");


           Session session = jsch.getSession(SFTPUSER,SFTPHOST,22 );
           System.out.println("session created.");

            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);

           session.connect();
           System.out.println("Connected");



        ////////////



         SimpleDateFormat dateFormatForFoldername = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");//dd/MM/yyyy
         Date currentDate = new Date();
         String folderDateFormat = dateFormatForFoldername.format(currentDate);
         String command = "scp -i "+Pemfilepath+" -r "+targetFolder+" "+"user@xx.xxx.xx.xxx:/var/www/html/projects/demo_reports/"+folderDateFormat+"/";
         System.out.println(command);
        Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");

        //channel.setCommand(command);
        //channel.setErrStream(System.err);
        channel.connect();

        System.out.println("Files is up");

               channel.disconnect();
               session.disconnect();
               System.out.println("Disconnected");
        ////////////
    } catch (JSchException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    }
}
```

Comment: try to rename the file. maybe there are Problems with the blanks

Comment: I have tried but getting same issue

Comment: Have you tried `ssh` on command line?

Comment: yes for command line I am able to connect. 
I just need to fire a command which connect transfer my file at the same time

Comment: scp  -i /Users/Demo/Downloads/AIRTEL\ \(2\).pem -r  /Users/Demo/Desktop/Danny/April-24   ubuntu@xx.xxx.xx.xxx:/var/www/html/projects/demo_reports/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In an another approch I have used sh exector directly from my local without connecting to the server first

`"echo "+pass+" | "+"sudo -S` Worked for me

My full code seems like below :-

```
String pass = "\"Yourpassword\"";
                out.println("echo "+pass+" | "+"sudo -S scp -i "+Pemfilepath+" -r "+targetFolder+" "+"user@xx.xxx.xx.xxx:/var/www/html/projects/demoproject");
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing cannot work. You cannot upload a file by only executing a command on the remote server. Where would the server take the file contents from? It cannot magically access your local files.

See the [official JSch `ScpTo.java` example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ScpTo.java.html) for a correct implementation of SCP upload.

Comment: I am new to this. so yes don't know what is happening in the background.  I am using window os . I have tried your example code as it is not working for me. That code is exit on the very first stage :-     if(arg.length!=2){
      System.err.println("usage: java ScpTo file1 user@remotehost:file2");
      System.exit(-1);
    }

Comment: Do I am missing some steps. can you please clearify more so I can exeucte the command accordingly

Comment: Just remove all references to `arg` and replace them with the paths and credentials you want to use. See the variables `lfile`, `user`, `host` and `rfile` + call `session.setPassword` to provide password, instead of using interactive login (remove `session.setUserInfo(ui)`). - Of course the code uploads a single file. Do you have to loop it to upload all files from a folder.

Comment: For some background, see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/40066370/850848