# JSch - Explaining SCP stream reading

Tags: java, ssh, scp, jsch

I'm having hard times trying to understand example codes from JSch library.

For example say, that I want to understand [this code](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ScpFrom.java.html) (example of scpFrom). I can't understand how that buffer, declared on line 56, works. How can that buffer contain for example read,write,execute flags, file size and first 7 chars of file name? I thought that when I read file with stream, that I'm reading contents of that file, not its filename etc...

Maybe I can't read Java documentation at all. I'm really confused by those examples and I don't want to use some library when I can't understand even examples :)

Can you suggest me what should I read or where are documented contents of that stream?
Another pearl for me is line 77, how can that code get filesize? 0 * 10L + first char in buff - char 0 ? I just don't get it...

Thank you all and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code implements the SCP protocol. So the stream represents the protocol stream, not mere file contents.

One of the main SCP protocol commands is `C` that starts a file transfer.

The `C` command has syntax:

```
C<mode> <size> <name>
```

It's a human-readable string. The code you refer to, parses the string.

---

See also [Explanation for SCP protocol implementation in JSch library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26220381/850848).