# Download all files in directory with SCP protocol using JSch

Tags: java, scp, jsch

I've been trying to retrieve a list of files that have file names that don't contain the string "-ingested-" via SCP (my manager doesn't want to use SFTP) from a remote server.

The files are zip files with at least one .txt file in them and a related .txt.count file.

So once I did some research on java libraries that allow retrieval of files via SCP, I broke the task down as follows:

1. Connect to the remote server (key authentication only) using JSch - done
2. Run a command that retrieves a specific file via SCP - done
3. Run a command that retrieves all the files in the specified directory via SCP - stuck on this, can't find any examples of doing this in JSch
4. Run a command that retrieves all the files in the specified directory that have file names that do NOT contain the string "-ingested-" in it
5. Rename all the files on the remote server that do not have the string "-ingested-" in their file name, and add the string "-ingested-" to their file name. 
   This is so that when I go to retrieve the files from the server a couple of hours later, I don't retrieve the ones I have already read in.

I'm currently stumped on step 3 as I don't seem to be able to find a example of this anywhere.

Below is the code for step 1 and 2:

```
final JSch jsch = new JSch();

final String authenticationKeyFilePath = "/var/myprivatekey.rsa";

jsch.addIdentity(authenticationKeyFilePath);

final String knownHostFilePath = "/home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts";

jsch.setKnownHosts(knownHostFilePath);

final String userName = "p";
final String host = "example.com";
final int port = 22;

final Session session = jsch.getSession(userName, host, port);

session.connect();

final String channelType = "exec";

final Channel channel = session.openChannel(channelType);

final String query = "scp -f /home/download/50347_SENT_20170614_025807.txt.count";

((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(query);

// Todo: Dispose of these streams if necessary.
final OutputStream outputStream = channel.getOutputStream();
final InputStream inputStream = channel.getInputStream();

channel.connect();

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
buffer[0] = 0;

final int outputStreamOffset = 0;
final int outputStreamLength = 1;
outputStream.write(buffer, outputStreamOffset, outputStreamLength);
outputStream.flush();

while (true) {
    final int c = checkAck(inputStream);

    if (c != 'C') break;

    // read '0644 '
    inputStream.read(buffer, 0, 5);

    long filesize = 0L;

    while (true) {
        if (inputStream.read(buffer, 0, 1) < 0) break;

        if (buffer[0] == ' ') break;
        filesize = filesize * 10L + (long)(buffer[0] - '0');
    }

    String file = null;

    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        inputStream.read(buffer, i, 1);

        if (buffer[i] == (byte)0x0a){
            file = new String(buffer, 0, i);
            break;
        }
    }

    // send '\0'
    buffer[0] = 0;
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, 1);
    outputStream.flush();

    // read a content of lfile
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    int foo;

    while (true) {
        if (buffer.length < filesize) foo = buffer.length;
        else foo = (int)filesize;
        foo = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, foo);

        if (foo < 0){
            // error
            break;
        }

        fos.write(buffer, 0, foo);
        filesize -= foo;

        if (filesize == 0L) break;
    }

    final String textFromDownloadedFile = fos.toString();  

    fos.close();
    fos = null;

    if (checkAck(inputStream) != 0) System.exit(0);

    // send '\0'
    buffer[0] = 0;
    outputStream.write(buffer, outputStreamOffset, outputStreamLength);
    outputStream.flush();
}

session.disconnect();

System.exit(0);
```

So in an ideal world, I would change the query string to something that matches what I want in step 4 and read them into a string list or whatever is most efficient, then I can store them and move onto step 5.
Any help is much appreciated.

p.s. If there is an easier to use Java SCP library out there with a corporation friendly licence, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Use a command like:

```
scp -r -d -f /remote/path/*
```

And then loop over the files that the server sends to you. What your code seems to do already.

---

Note that I'm afraid you will have troubles implementing the step 4 using the SCP protocol. The *"NOT contain"* condition is troublesome.

Use SFTP! The SCP is legacy obsolete protocol.

Of course, what you can do is to execute `ls` shell command. Parse the results to find list of all files. And then filter them locally.

---

Some related questions:

- [Explanation for SCP protocol implementation in JSch library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26220381/850848)
- [JSch - Explaining SCP stream reading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41636827/850848)
- [JSch SCP file transfer using "exec" channel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40066370/850848)

Comment: In the code, I believe that I am ssh'd onto the server, so running scp on the remote server. Which is why I think in the scp command I am referring to the directory on the remote server without the username and host. If this is true, and that's plausible as I know VERY little about ssh\scp, then how would I refer back to a directory on the machine\vm that the code is running on?
With the command that you posted, I now seem to get more than one file name back. Not sure whether I'm getting the actual file data too (hopefully!), but I'll look into that.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You execute `scp` in server mode (`-f`) on the server. And it feeds you the files one by one. You get the individual file names (including relative paths) in `file` variable. - *"how would I refer back to a directory on the machine\vm that the code is running on"* - Not sure what you mean. What do you want to refer to it for? You know what path you have passed to remote `scp`, so you know where the files are coming from.

Comment: I've added links to related questions, which may help you understanding how SCP works.